# How come whenever I enter the correct password, this always says it is incorrect?

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra

How come even when I enter a correct password, it says it is wrong. When I compare the 2 passwords, it says they are the same but when I try and sign in, it says my password is wrong? BTW the password comes from a hash I have in a file.

```
post "/login" do
   username = "#{params[:username]}"
   #password = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest("#{params[:password]}"))
   password ="#{params[:password]}"
   puts(password)
   $users=eval(IO.read("users.emy"))
   puts($users.values_at(username))
   puts($users.to_s)
   if $users.values_at(username)!=password
     puts "Wrong password!"
     redirect "/"
   end
   if $users.values_at(username)==password
     redirect "/dash"
   end
end
```

Comment: Difficult to tell: there's no code here. See [ask]

Comment: You are simply reading to an `IO` and using eval? Have you made sure this returns the Hash? Why not use a standard format like `YAML` and then you can parse it to a Hash easily rather than relying on eval to try and figure out what you want? There are other issues with your current concept but that is where I would start.

Comment: @electrithm if your issue has been silved, please select an answer below and hit the checkmark. Otherwise, submit your own answer with proper attribution and details.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're comparing strings, you should use something like

```
unless $users[username].eql? password
  puts "Wrong password!"
  redirect "/"
end
if $users[username].eql? password
  redirect "/dash"
end
```

`#values_at` returns an array. See: [#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). Since `params[:password]` should be a string, I believe this is what you want.

I'm making a whole lot of assumptions here, because I don't know the format of `users.emy`. Let me know if I'm made a wrong assumption somewhere.

On a side note,

```
username = "#{params[:username]}"
password = "#{params[:password]}"
```

Can be written as

```
username = params[:username]
password = params[:password]
```

Or simply used as `params[:username]` or `params[:password]`.